# How to insert an image or geometric shape into WordPress homepage

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want to insert a little green square between words on my WordPress homepage. I wrote the html:

```
<div class="x"><center><p 
style="border:10px; border. 
style:solid; 
border-color:#00ff00; padding: 
0.0em; width: 2px; height: 
2px;">
</p></center></div>
```

Pen: https://codepen.io/adsler/pen/KOXzPw

Site: http://4309.co.uk

Every other page I can access and edit but not the same for homepage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.

go to your appearance, customise, add'text widget' then add the html code. If you were to add the css, you would need to go to --> appearance --> additional css

Have a great day!
Austin

Comment: if you could up vote that would be awesome! also, any other questions I can answer for html or css

Comment: Great. Thanks. Up voted you but doesn't show because I don't have enough points.

Answer (score 0):

It will be work

`<div class="x"><center><p >Write Something<span style="border:10px; border-style:solid; border-color:#00ff00; padding: 0.0em; width: 2px; height: 2px;"></span> New</p></center></div>`

Pen: https://codepen.io/shakil-shaikh/pen/xvXdEX

Comment: Thanks, but where do I put it?

Answer (score 0):

3 divs. Div one for top, div two for the square, and div three for bottom. If you need more explanation, I can elaborate.

Comment: Yes please, where do I put it?

Answer (score 0):

Check below.

Box ‘one’ would be where text one goes, ‘center’ is where you would style the geometric shape, and ‘box2’ is where the second string of text will go.

When I get to my computer I’ll see if I can write out the full code for you to use.

```
<div id=box1></>
<div id=center></>
<div id=box2></>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to accomplish?

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<meta char="utf-8">
<title>box test</title>
<style>
#content {
 margin:25px auto;
}
#text-1 {
border:#000000 2px solid;
width:20%;
height:20%;
margin-bottom:10px;
}
#shape {
border:#000000 2px solid;
width:20%;
height:20%;
}
#text-3 {
border:#000000 2px solid;
width:20%;
height:20%;
margin-top:10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id=content>
<div id=text-1>text one</div>
<div id=shape>shape</div>
<div id=text-3>text two</div>
</div>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: `<div class="x"><center><p >Write Something<span style="border:10px; border-style:solid; border-color:#00ff00; padding: 0.0em; width: 2px; height: 2px;"></span> New</p></center></div>

Pen: https://codepen.io/shakil-shaikh/pen/xvXdEX` like this. But where do I put it in my site?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work? the position property allows you to put your div's anywhere on the website. Just remember that the attribute allows for stacking. Just use the left/right/top/bottom attribute.

```css
#container {
  width:1000px;
}
#x {
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
background-color:blue;
}
#center {
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:150px;
}
#y {
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:300px;
background-color:#ffff00;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div id="x">Write something</div>
<div id="center">middle</div>
<div id="y">New</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I know where to put the css but, forgive me for not understanding, where to I put the html? I can insert it on individual pages but no such option exists in WordPress to insert the html on front page?

Comment: You could copy and paste on each page or use a jquery code that can be found through a search on google or W3 schools.

Comment: Otherwise, yes you can use it on individual pages also.

Comment: Then I'd have it on each page? I just want it on homepage.

Comment: go to your homepage, go to 'text' then add the html code. If you were to add the css, you would need to go to --> appearance --> editor.

Comment: yes, you could actually add the html to a text widget. Also if you did not wanted to edit the css source code, then you could just add the 'style' to the elements themselves.

Comment: `go to your appearance, customise, add'text widget' then add the html code. If you were to add the css, you would need to go to --> appearance --> additional css ` that's the correct answer. If you post I'll mark correct. I can always put an src in if I need an image. Thanks

Comment: You can if you like, thanks, but it's like this. `<div class="x"><center><p >Write Something<span style="border:10px; border-style:solid; border-color:#00ff00; padding: 0.0em; width: 2px; height: 2px;"></span> New</p></center></div>`

Comment: add the attribute margin:25px; and that should do it for you.

Comment: Yes, if you post this`go to your appearance, customise, add'text widget' then add the html code. If you were to add the css, you would need to go to --> appearance --> additional css <div class="x"><center><p >Write Something<span style="border:10px; border-style:solid; border-color:#00ff00; padding: 0.0em; width: 2px; height: 2px;"></span> New</p></center></div>` I will